Is there any research on what makes a video “satisfying?

I am new to this stack exchange so please let me know how I can improve my question. Also, I do not know what tags to put on this question besides reference-request so I would appreciate if someone could help me out with that. I thought this question might be on-topic here because the concept of understanding what makes something satisfying seems like it is related to psychology.

“Satisfying” videos across pretty much every social media platform and have a wide range of content. There are many YouTube videos and articles online explaining what makes a video “satisfying” but I have not found any formal research on this. The only real data I see is analytics from social media sites such as views and likes but this data is heavily affected by outside factors such as the algorithm and the following of the user that posts the video.
Also, I know that satisfaction is subjective but there are definitely some trends and main themes such as things perfectly fitting together and perfect loops. There are also some interactions between materials (I think they only exist with cgi so I can’t really be more specific) that just seem satisfying. I have noticed that a lot of these involve something melting.
Has any formal research been done regarding this?

My feeling is that this question is too broad: A "video" can be anything from a few second clip to a multi-hour production, anything from an art piece to a documentary, etc. Surely what makes a music video satisfying differs from what works in a science-fiction show episode. I'm also skeptical that anyone in the industry uses the term "satisfying" to describe viewer reactions. Data such as views and likes is much more likely exactly what is used, with statistical corrections for algorithm and channel following. I recommend narrowing down both the scope of the question and measurement criteria.
